# How to change markdown theme back to default in Visual Studio Code (VSCode)?

Tags: markdown, editor, visual-studio-code

A few weeks ago, I update my visual studio code, and my markdown editor theme changed.

The new editor theme has changed to the picture bellow.
For me, this editor is inconvenient, and I want to change it back to the default markdown editor.
I had check my vscode extensions, I didn't download any editor extensions.

##### New markdown Editor

[image: New markdown Editor]

##### Default Markdown Editor

[image: Default Markdown Editor]

How could I change back to default editor?

Answer (score 4):

late...but this is the solution (screenshots):

[step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAEzw.png)

[step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ftg5b.png)

[step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ea9Vh.png)

[step 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sRfq.png)

Answer (score 2):

Go to the extensions (or press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>) in Visual Studio Code, and under extensions go to the extensions installed, click on the theme that is currently installed, and you can see an option to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to my own question.
I delete all themes of vscode and change back to the default vscode theme solved this problem...

Maybe one of the theme will change the default editor to vditor(The New markdown Editor)

Comment: I have no themes installed, no markdown extensions either... and still have this weird white ideogram-written markdown WYSIWYG showing up... any clues?

Answer (score 1):

You must have installed an extension based on [`vditor`](https://b3log.org/vditor/), such as the [`Office Viewer(Markdown Editor)`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cweijan.vscode-office) extension. It seems that even after the extension is uninstalled, markdown files still load `vditor`. On Windows, I had to delete `%APPDATA%\Code\Cache\Cache_data` and `%APPDATA%\Code\CachedExtensionVSIXs` to fix this. Be sure to first backup both folders if you want to try this approach!